# The Data Captured in Microsoft Form need to be loaded to the SharePoint list using power apps?.Can anyone help me out

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

The Data Captured in Microsoft Form need to be loaded to the SharePoint list using power apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerApps is used to design forms.
If you want to save data automatically from Microsoft Forms to SharePoint, I suggest you use MS Flow with **[Record form responses in SharePoint](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/2be590104bdd11e78896d10a96d3fac3/record-form-responses-in-sharepoint/)** template to achieve it.

Below is my test for your reference:
My form is:
[image]

My SharePoint List is:
[image]

I used **Record form responses in SharePoint** template and set it as:
[image]

When a user response the form, the data will be saved into the SharePoint list:
[image]

If I misunderstand your meaning, feel free to reply.

Comment: Can we create a button in MS Forms (eg: Cancel button or reset button)?

Comment: No, per my knowledge, currently there is no way to add custom buttons in MS Forms. There is a user voice about this similar topic, you can vote up it.  https://microsoftforms.uservoice.com/forums/386451-welcome-to-microsoft-forms-suggestion-box/suggestions/40403074--return-button

Comment: Ok thanks for the information.