# How to create flow to add new member Office 365 to Sharepoint list when someone used Forms to say "Hello"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow, power-automate

I have a little problem, because I don't know how to create flow to add new member Office 365 to Sharepoint list when someone used Forms to say "Hello"?

1. I have FORM which a fields: a) name, b)surname, c) e-mail, d) field with text to say: "Hello!" or something.
2. If someone new add new form with information from 1. - flow create a new field in Sharepoint list with column: name, surname, e-mail, field with text to say: "Hello!" or something.

How can I made this connection FORM <> FLOW (power automate) <> Sharepoint list to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to save the responses from Forms into a SharePoint list. You can use MS Flow to achieve it.

There is a template called [Record form responses in SharePoint](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/2be590104bdd11e78896d10a96d3fac3/record-form-responses-in-sharepoint/), you can use it,

A similar thread for your reference:
[The Data Captured in Microsoft Form need to be loaded to the SharePoint list using power apps?.Can anyone help me out](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280349/the-data-captured-in-microsoft-form-need-to-be-loaded-to-the-sharepoint-list-usi)